# Very simple inquiry about Java OO programming in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, class

Okay, so I am trying to wrap my head around how to get stuff done with Java (I come from C++, Python, PHP etc.).  I'm quite familiar with the language itself and OO principles, but less so familiar with building projects, stitching the dependencies together, and other aspects of the ritual and repetition that surrounds putting together a functioning Java program.

If you have resources to suggest (good tutorials etc.), I wholeheartedly encourage you to do so.

My question is this:

I have a new Eclipse project.  I make a class, let's say `Guitar`, that I want to use in another class in the same project, `Musician` (this is where my `main()` method resides).  How do I import and use `Guitar` in the source for the `Musician` class?

There's got to be something obvious I'm overlooking here, but I've tried a bunch of different things to no avail.  Just tangling myself up into a mess.  :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add `import thepackage.Guitar;` just after the package declaration of your class Musician. When Eclipse detects a problem (class not found), hovering the problem red mark with your mouse opens a menu with suggestions (like adding an import). But please, do a few java tutorials.

Comment: Do you mean like an import statement atop your main class? `import Guitar;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this. And since you are using eclipse you can do CTRL+SHIFT+O and it will auto-import the classes needed.

```
public class Musician() {

       public Musician() {
             Guitar guitar = new Guitar();
       }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that helped the most.  Can't believe I was overlooking something so simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `Guitar` in your code and press ctrl + shift + O to add the import. Alternatively, you can highlight the class reference in the code and Eclipse will ask if you want to import it, or you could simply type the import yourself: `import com.foo.Guitar;` at the top of the class.

Answer (score 3):

You asked it as an Eclipse-specific question, so:

Start coding and Eclipse will tell you that `Guitar` is not known. Along with that error it will also provide a clickable suggestion to add the missing import.

---

Of course you could add the import by hand, but that is not Eclipse-specific, it is pure Java basics:

```
import Guitar;
```

If you simply add the new class to the source folder in Eclipse, it will be in the "default namespace" and the above import will be correct. For "real" projects you will want to use explicit namespaces though. You can add them by right-clicking on the source folder and choosing "new..namespace". In that case you will have to import the correct namespace of course:

```
import name.of.my.name.space.Guitar;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the same package, there is nothing to do.

If it's in another package, you need

```
package com.my.another.pakkage;
import com.my.pakkage.Guitar;

class Musician {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a source directory tree, and give your source files packages. Then you can use import xxxx to import your files into other files. There are tutorials out there, but fundamentally, if your source home is a directory called "src", and you have a file in "src/foo", that source file should declare "package foo;"

Answer (score 1):

Put your classes in a package (not the default one, give it a name). Sub-packages are allowed.

Then you'll be able to import a class with this code :

```
import myPackage.mySubPackage.MyClass;
```